Error message when trying to execute a .py file in macOS terminal (zsh)
I'v got a problem.. I've installed python through HomeBrew but when i try to execute a simple hello.py file by typing python3 hello.py
it gives me this error message :
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/<userName>/Desktop/Projects/hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
could anyone hint me on a practical solution ?
Thanks to whoever will read this !
PS: I'm not new to python programming but it's been like 3 or 4 years that I didn't program in python so i don't even know what to test or where to look to solve my problem...

Make sure that your in the same directory as the Python file, if not, run cd /path/to/file/directory first.

How about creating a file ~/Desktop/Projects/hello.py? From the error message, I would conclude that this file does not exist. What does ls -l ~/Desktop/Projects/hello.py say?

Ensure the file exists in the directory your terminal is in. You can view your current directory by the command pwd, you can change directories via cd [DIR].
For example, after opening a new terminal, cd to your project, then create a new Python file and execute it.
~ user$ cd ~/Desktop/Projects
~/Desktop/Projects user$ echo 'print("Rainbows are cool!")' > hello.py
~/Desktop/Projects user$ python hello.py
Rainbows are cool!
~/Desktop/Projects user$ 


Thanks ! like you said i wsn't in the right directory! MyBad... !

It’s seems that you’re not in the same folder as you python file in the terminal view.
